# Making A Gameshow like application?

Tags: powerpoint

my friend is holding a charity quiz night and I was wondering if there was any software that would be good to create an application where the user can choose from two categories and then see a question from that category, then move on to the next two categories and so on.

I thought of Powerpoint or Keynotes for this but they have a very linear slideshow structure is it possible to link to different slideshow from buttons maybe like macros?

Or is there any better software out there that would be a better tool for the job? Bearing in mind it needs to be able to be shown on a projector and without internet access.

Any help would be really great as Im not sure whats the best way to go about this?
Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a series of powerpoint slides with buttons for each option. You can splice in a little bit of VBScript to have to buttons keep track of the choises a user made, so that you can present the results in the end.

However with only a trivial bit of searching you could find out that there are dozens of quiz maker applications. I'm not sure which ones are good or bad. But try [this](http://www.bing.com/search?q=make%20your%20own%20quiz%20show%20applicaiton&go=&qs=n&sk=&form=QBRE&scope=web) query string. To find apps like ["Multiple Choise"](http://multiple-choice.software.article24h.com/) which looks pretty much like what you are looking for.